# SQL Server 2014 - How to select rows with no numerical values in fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnumeric

I'm trying to find Accounts that have nothing in the phone number field and nothing in the EmailAddress field. But when I use the ISNUMERIC function to filter our records with a phone number, I still get a few records with numbers in them.

My Code:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE (ISNUMERIC(DayTimePhone) = 0 OR DayTimePhone IS NULL)
  AND (DayTimePhone NOT LIKE '%[A-Z]%')
  AND ((EMailAddress IS NULL) OR (EMailAddress NOT LIKE '%[A-Z]%'))
```

The numbers I'm getting in the DayTimePhone field are:

```
604.123.1123
(604) 123-1234
(604) 234-5678
(604) 345-6789
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `LEN` to filter the columns by length of characters in the columns and find all records where those fields are empty. Something like this perhaps?

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE
    (LEN(ISNULL(DayTimePhone, '')) = 0 OR DayTimePhone IS NULL)
    AND ((EmailAddressIS NULL) OR (LEN(ISNULL(EmailAddress, '')) = 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other characters than just numbers in those values, so they ISNUMERIC() returns 0. You could do a select to get the values without special characters and then run your code.